# Delphi Class Parameter

Tags: delphi, class

I am trying to compose my own ThreadManager unit in Delphi and I have this so far:

```
unit uThreadManager;

interface

uses
  Classes,
  Windows;

type
  TCustomTThread = class (TThread)
  public
    TaskData : Pointer;
end;

type
  TWorkerThread = class(TObject)
  private
    TaskDataList : TList;
    TaskDataListCrit : TRTLCriticalSection;
    function ReadTotalTasks : Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property TotalTasks : Integer read ReadTotalTasks;
    function AddTask(Thread: TCustomTThread; Data: Pointer) : Integer;
    procedure Delete (Index : Integer);
end;

implementation

type
  PTaskData = ^TTaskData;
  TTaskData = record
  Thread          : TCustomTThread;
  TaskPointer     : Pointer;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Delete(Index: Integer);
var
  TaskData : PTaskData;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
  TaskData := TaskDataList.Items[Index];
  TaskDataList.Delete(Index);
  LeaveCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
  TaskData^.Thread.Free;
  Dispose(TaskData);
end;

function TWorkerThread.ReadTotalTasks;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
  result := TaskDataList.Count;
  LeaveCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
end;

destructor TWorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  DeleteCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
  TaskDataList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TWorkerThread.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  InitializeCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
  TaskDataList    := TList.Create;
end;

function TWorkerThread.AddTask(Thread: TCustomTThread; Data: Pointer) : Integer;
var
  NewTask : PTaskData;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
  New(NewTask);
  // I would like to create a new instance of TCustomTThread here!
  //NewTask^.Thread       := ...
  NewTask^.TaskPointer  := Data;
  result                := TaskDataList.Add (NewTask);
  LeaveCriticalSection(TaskDataListCrit);
end;

end.
```

I came across the problem with the parameter from my `AddTask` procedure...

Here is an example on what I am trying to do:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, uThreadManager;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

type
  TTheCustomThread = class (TCustomTThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTheCustomThread.Execute;
begin
 // My Code
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewWorkerThread : TWorkerThread;
begin
  NewWorkerThread := TWorkerThread.Create;
  NewWorkerThread.AddTask(TTheCustomThread, NIL);
end;

end.
```

this code gives me the error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(42): E2010 Incompatible types:
>   'TCustomTThread' and 'class of TTheCustomThread'

I could fix this by declaring a new `TTheCustomThread` var in the stack but I would like to avoid this cause I won't need it at all later and `AddTask` will create a new instance of `TTheCustomThread`. I could use TClass and then typecast to `TCustomThread` but I was wondering if there's anything else to make this work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `AddTask` is defined as so:

```
function AddTask(Thread: TCustomTThread; Data: Pointer) : Integer;
```

The first parameter that you pass is of type `TCustomTThread`. That is an *instance* of `TCustomTThread`.

You call the function like this:

```
AddTask(TTheCustomThread, nil);
```

Here you pass the class rather than an instance. Hence the compiler error.

Now, it seems that what you want to do is pass the class. Inside `AddTask` you wish to receive a class and then create a new instance. Declare a class type like so:

```
type
  TTheCustomThreadClass = class of TTheCustomThread;
```

Change `AddTask` to receive that type:

```
function AddTask(ThreadClass: TCustomTThreadClass; Data: Pointer) : Integer;
```

And inside the implementation, create an instance like this:

```
NewTask^.Thread := ThreadClass.Create;
```

Very likely you will want to declare the constructor of `TTheCustomThread` to be virtual to allow derived classes the freedom to define constructors that can be executed from your factory creation mechanism.